# How many valves per distance are common in veins?

Tags: blood, injections, venous-system

Veins have valves to prevent backflow of blood.  I am looking for a value the indicates on average how far apart those valves would be.

> There are valves in most veins to prevent backflow. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vein)

I have searched and not found a reference.  I am specifically interested in superficial veins of the arms, where vein access is generally acquired (*i.e. sticks for blood draw and/or IV therapy*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution of valves in the veins can vary greatly.

**FOREARM VEINS**

[Relationship of Common Vascular Anatomy to Cannulated Catheters (Hindawi, 2017)](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijvm/2017/5157914/):

> Veins of the antecubital fossa [anterior side of the elbow] were much less
>   likely to have valves, whereas veins of the hand and forearm were
>   nearly equal in the frequency of valves identified. In those vein
>   segments of the hand with valves, there were often multiple valves
>   identified within the 10 cm segment studied.

The [Table 2](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijvm/2017/5157914/tab2/) says that in adults the average distance between the vein valves in the hand is **6 cm,** in the forearm **7 cm** and at the front of the elbow **17 cm.**

**LEG VEINS**

**The great saphenous vein in the inner thigh** is commonly used as a graft to replace atherosclerotic coronary arteries.

[The Relative Position of Paired Valves at Venous Junctions Suggests Their Role in Modulating Three-dimensional Flow Pattern in Veins (European Journal of Vascular and Endovascular Surgery, 2012)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1078588412004303)

> All studied valves were located **between 3 and 5 cm apart.** The mean
>   distance between the two valves in the GSV [great saphenous vein] was
>   3.8 ± 0.4 cm...

[Lower Extremity Venous Anatomy (Seminars in Interventional Radiology, 2005)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3036282/):

> The number of **deep venous valves** increases from cranial to caudal.
>   Unlike the infrainguinal veins, the iliac veins rarely contain valves.
>   Detailed anatomic dissections have shown valves to be present in only
>   1.2% of common iliac veins, 27% of external iliac veins (39.6% on the right versus 14.6% on the left), and 10.1% of internal iliac veins.
>   There are on average **five deep venous valves between the inguinal
>   ligament and popliteal fossa,** although the number varies from two to
>   nine. Their arrangement is variable, but the external iliac and common
>   femoral vein above the saphenofemoral junction usually have one valve
>   at most; the femoral vein above the adductor canal has three or more
>   valves; the distal superficial femoral and popliteal veins have one or
>   two valves; and the **tibial/peroneal veins have numerous valves
>   spaced at ∼2-cm intervals.**

**The small saphenous vein at the back of the lower leg:**

[The anatomy of the small saphenous vein: Fascial and neural relations, saphenofemoral junction, and valves (Journal of Vascular Surgery, 2010)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0741521409018291?via%3Dihub)

> A most proximal valve was present in only 94% at a mean distance of
>   **1.2 cm to the small saphenous vein orifice** [popliteal vein behind the knee]. A consecutive distal valve was only present in 65% with a
>   mean distance of **5.1 cm.**

Comment: Although OP didn't ask for it, adding the numbers for leg veins would be interesting and would make the answer more complete.

Comment: I added leg veins.